# (Swift)(Firebase) Getting EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with Facebook login

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am creating an app that uses Facebook to login and retrieves your profile picture to use as the profile picture for the app. This is the code:

```
if let user = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser {
  // User is signed in.
  let name = user.displayName
  let email = user.email
  let photoUrl = user.photoURL
  let uid = user.uid;

  self.profileName.text = name

  // ERROR: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)
  let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: photoUrl!)
  self.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data!)


}
```

This error only happens when using login NOT through Facebook. When doing it through Facebook it works fine. I have a hunch that the error arises because if I log in regularly (not through Facebook) this line will say "there is no photo, what are you talking about?" and crash. However, I am unsure as to how to circumvent this issue. I am using Firebase.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value" mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170456/what-does-fatal-error-unexpectedly-found-nil-while-unwrapping-an-optional-valu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This means that `photoUrl` is nil. The code crashes because you're using the forced unwrap operator `!`. You should safely unwrap it instead:

```
if let photoUrl = photoUrl, data = NSData(contentsOfURL: photoUrl) {
    self.profilePic.image = UIImage(data: data)
else {
    print("No photo")
}
```